# Show all children of li that is shown and that matches input with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, input

Currently have some html and JS which I want to use to search through revision notes. My aim is that when the keywords in the parents of a ul/li equal the input, all children (like the all * selector in css) will be shown.

Purpose: if an li contains given input then show all of that li's children (e.g. example 1, 2, 3) - if an li next to *the li that contains input* do not contain input the hide that.

Examples of different input and desired output in style:

**Example 1**

Input = keyword1 or Input = Parent 1

Parent 1 keyword1 *(style="display:block;")*
Child keyword2 (style="display:block;")
"Grand" Child keyword3 (style="display:block;")
Child 2 keyword4 (style="display:block;")
"Grand" Child keyword5 (style="display:block;")
Parent 2 keyword6 *(style="display:none;")*
Child 2 keyword7 (style="display:none;")
"Grand" Child keyword8 (style="display:none;")
Child 3 keyword9 (style="display:none;")
"Grand" Child keyword10 (style="display:none;")

**Example 2**

Input = keyword2 or Input = keyword3

Parent 1 keyword1 *(style="display:block;")*
Child keyword2 (style="display:block;")
"Grand" Child keyword3 (style="display:block;")
Child 2 keyword4 *(style="display:none;")*
"Grand" Child keyword5 (style="display:none;")
Parent 2 keyword6 (style="display:none;")
Child 2 keyword7 (style="display:none;")
"Grand" Child keyword8 (style="display:none;")
Child 3 keyword9 (style="display:none;")
"Grand" Child keyword10 (style="display:none;")

**Example 3**

Input = keyword4 or Input = keyword5

Parent 1 keyword1 *(style="display:block;")*
Child keyword2 (style="display:none;")
"Grand" Child keyword3 (style="display:none;")
Child 2 keyword4 *(style="display:block;")*
"Grand" Child keyword5 (style="display:block;")
Parent 2 keyword6 (style="display:none;")
Child 2 keyword7 (style="display:none;")
"Grand" Child keyword8 (style="display:none;")
Child 3 keyword9 (style="display:none;")
"Grand" Child keyword10 (style="display:none;")

Currently when an input is entered the function only shows the exact li that matches - I want all children to be shown. So how? Thanks. See code below.

```js
function searchTitle() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  window.status = filter;
  ul = document.getElementById("List");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i];
    if (a.textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a.style.display = "";
    } else {
      a.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <body>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="searchTitle()" placeholder="Search through notes" title="Type in a keyword">
    <ul id="List">
      <li>
        Parent 1 keyword1
        <ul>
          <li>
            Child keyword2
            <ul>
              <li>&quot;Grand&quot; Child keyword3</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            Child 2 keyword4
            <ul>
              <li>&quot;Grand&quot; Child keyword5</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        Parent 2 keyword6
        <ul>
          <li>
            Child 2 keyword7
            <ul>
              <li>&quot;Grand&quot; Child keyword8</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            Child 3 keyword9
            <ul>
              <li>&quot;Grand&quot; Child keyword10</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const $input = document.querySelector("#myInput");
$input.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    const query = e.target.value;
    const $ul = document.querySelector("ul");
    const $lis = $ul.querySelectorAll("li");
    const $matchedLis = [...$lis].filter(($li) => $li.textContent.match(query));
    [...$lis].forEach(($li) => $li.classList.add("hide"));
    [...$matchedLis].forEach(($li) => {
      $li.classList.remove("hide");
      [...$li.querySelectorAll("li")].map(($li) => $li.classList.remove("hide"));
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3bh2paow/

What it does:
Fires event on input. [Not keypress]
I use variables that begin with `$` for readability, they imply dom elements.
I hide elements by adding hide class to element. [Not inline JS]

Steps of code:
Filter all lis which match the query string (the value in input)
Hide all LIs
Unhide (by removing hide class) of elements which were filtered.
Unhide all children elements of previous step.

Comment: When "Parent 1" or "keyword1" is entered I wanted to show all children (Child keyword2 and "Grand" Child keyword3). The JS fiddle doesn't show all children.

Comment: Updated. I added the extra part you wanted.

Comment: Could this script to be changed to work with all children as well? At the moment only works with one child list item. For instance if Child keyword2 and "Grand" Child keyword3 were duplicated and named Child keyword22 "Grand" Child keyword33 and the input was keyword22 then then parallel list item containing keyword2 would still be shown.

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly your search criteria isn't normal behavior.

A search for "Pets" doesnt match "Pet". Nor does "keyword22" match "keyword2"

Comment: But to answer your question, yes, it's still possible. Are you sure you want that behavior? If I type into google "Telephone" I see words that begin with "Telephone" or with more characters, not words that match "Tele"

Comment: Clarified the purpose in an edit on the original post. Also provided more examples of what I would like to happen to li for a given input.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is setting `display: none` to every `li` that does not match the search keyword. But since you use `.textContent`, the parents are not affected (they match anyway).

So now for the childrens, I achieved it using a recursive function to loop through all the childNodes of a *match* , until there is none, and set the `display: ""` on them if it is a `LI` element.

I used a `setTimeout` to ensure the recursion occurs when the loop of `searchTitle` has finished. Notice the `let a` instead of a `var`. That is to make sure to pass the matching element.

```js
function searchTitle() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  window.status = filter;
  ul = document.getElementById("List");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    let a = li[i];
    if (a.textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a.style.display = "";
      setTimeout(()=>displayChilds(a),1)  // Call the recusrsive function
    } else {
      a.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

// Recursive function called from a matching element
function displayChilds(el){
  if(el.hasChildNodes){
    el.childNodes.forEach(child => {
      if(child.tagName == "LI"){
        child.style.display = ""
      }
      displayChilds(child)  // Recusion occurs here
    })
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <body>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="searchTitle()" placeholder="Search through notes" title="Type in a keyword">
    <ul id="List">
      <li>
        Parent 1 keyword1
        <ul>
          <li>
            Child keyword2
            <ul>
              <li>&quot;Grand&quot; Child keyword3</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        Parent 2 keyword4
        <ul>
          <li>
            Child keyword5
            <ul>
              <li>&quot;Grand&quot; Child keyword6</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This script only works with one child list item. For instance if Child keyword2 and "Grand" Child keyword3 were duplicated and named Child keyword22
"Grand" Child keyword33 and the input was keyword22 then then parallel list item containing keyword2 would still be shown.

Comment: It is unclear what would be hidden then.

Comment: Clarified the purpose in an edit on the original post. Also provided more examples of what I would like to happen to li for a given input.