# Javascript to filter list items and their children by keywords

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, input

Can someone correct this js script. When I search "keyword2" or "keyword3" it shows the list items and their children containing these keywords but also shows the siblings and their children which contain different keywords, e.g. "keyword4" or "keyword5". I believe the issue is within the last 5 lines of JS. Also can you make the script non-case sensitive. Thanks.

```js
const $input = document.querySelector("#myInput");
$input.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  const query = e.target.value;
  const $ul = document.querySelector("ul");
  const $lis = $ul.querySelectorAll("li");
  const $matchedLis = [...$lis].filter(($li) => $li.textContent.match(query));
  [...$lis].forEach(($li) => $li.classList.add("hide"));
  [...$matchedLis].forEach(($li) => {
    $li.classList.remove("hide");
    [...$li.querySelectorAll("li")].map(($li) => $li.classList.remove("hide"));
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search through notes" title="Type in a keyword">
  <ul id="List">
    <li>
      Parent 1 keyword1
      <ul>
        <li>
          Child keyword2
          <ul>
            <li>"Grand" Child keyword3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          Child keyword4
          <ul>
            <li>"Grand" Child keyword5</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      Parent 2 keyword6
      <ul>
        <li>
          Child keyword7
          <ul>
            <li>"Grand" Child keyword8</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          Child keyword9
          <ul>
            <li>"Grand" Child keyword10</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The problem is that the textContent of an LI includes the text of all the LIs nested inside it. So when you search for `keyword2`, it matches the parent `keyword1`. And then you unhide all the LIs inside that.

Comment: You should not post the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71316391/show-all-children-of-li-that-is-shown-and-that-matches-input-with-javascript#) multiple time.

Comment: So how would I fix this @Barmar ?

Comment: I'm not sure, it's tricky. It would probably help if you put the messages that you want to filter into their own elements, like `<span class="keywords">Child keyword2<span>`